# Can I read MIME encoded email in Livecode

Tags: mime, livecode

I am busy with an app that requires me to read the contents of .msg and .eml files (MIME emails?) created in Outlook into my Livecode application. Can this be done and/or is there an example somewhere that I can use as base?
Regards
Danny

Comment: If you can figure out the .msg and .eml formats, then it can be done. These formats aren't too difficult. You'll need the commands and functions binaryEncode, binaryDecode, base64encode, base64decode. 
It would be best if you add your attempts to your question (in StackOverlow, you're supposed to show what you have tried so far) and then we can help.

Comment: Thank you @mark. The binaryEncode and binaryDecode were not presented as an answer from documentation and all the searches on all the various forums. So, it is difficult to show what I have done when I am actually asking what it is I should try to look at and you have now kindly answered that for me - thank you.

Comment: I agree that the built-in documentation lacks good search features. I added my remark about including some code just because that's how SO works.

Comment: The file name extensions do not reliably identify the message format; different clients at different times have used them for all kinds of proprietary and/or legacy formats. If the files are plainly human-readable then they are most likely in an RFC822-compatible and thus (implicitly if not explicitly) MIME. But if they originate from Outlook, this is almost certainly not the case (I don't think it's possible to get standard format out of Outlook, except by forwarding as attachents, and even then it might contain stuff that Microsoft invented out of thin air, especially if you are on Exchange)

Comment: Thanks - You are right and anything Microsoft is a challenge when you want to try and build something "standard" for their various versions. Exchange remains to be a challenge whether you are a user or a developer.